# How to Download files from Ubuntuone to Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, downloads

While I've been working with Ubuntu, I used `Ubuntu One` to backup my critical files.

I didn't store files in the folder `Ubuntu One`, I marked my folder `Documents` to sync.

Well now on website I can see all my files, but I don't know how download all of them to my PC with Win 7 installed.

I installed the beta client `Ubuntu One for Windows`, but I don't know what else I can do, except downloading each file manually.

Comment: I entered my login and pass, and it even trying to find files to sync on my pc, but allready uploaded files from ubuntu still only on cloud

Comment: With the current windows client, you should be able to sync everything. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

For now, Ubuntu One for Windows *only* synchronizes files and folders in your `Ubuntu One` folder. This restriction will be going away with the next beta.